# JDBC querying and inserting into arbitrary tables

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

What is a good way to query (always selecting all columns) and insert into arbitrary Oracle database tables using JDBC? I created the following method (haven't tested it yet) for retrieving any table's attribute names and types (I need the names for display purposes):

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> retrieveTableAttributes(String tableName) throws SQLException{
  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
  DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
  ResultSet resultSet = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
  int i = 0;
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    attributes.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
    attributes.get(i).put(resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME"), resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME"));
    i++;
  }
  resultSet.close();
  return attributes;
}
```

I found this method [PreparedStatement#setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) which I think can be used to set a value for any arbitrary column type (in this case I would need to get the column type as an int instead of the type name), but I am not sure about this. So, is there a better way for setting and more importantly getting values from columns with arbitrary types? If it helps, I am trying to create a Java EE GUI tool for manipulating a database (adding, deleting, updating rows from any table in the database).

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to get the type code from a named type using reflection:

```
public int getTypeByName(String name) {
    for (Field field : java.sql.Types.class.getFields()) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName())) return (Integer) field.get(null);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Note that the TYPE_NAME column is probably not guaranteed to match Oracle's column support. A safer bet might just be to rely on the driver to make the right conversion choices using the untyped setObject and getObject methods.